# past perfect without a simple past as anchor

Tags: past-perfect

I'd like to know if the past perfect can be used without a simple past as an anchor. What are the conditions on such use? It seems to contradict what typical ESL books say.

> a. Thanks to the marketing tactics, unprepared shoppers usually buy products that they **hadn’t intended** on getting.

> b. Thanks to the marketing tactics, unprepared shoppers usually buy products that they **hadn’t intended** to.

Comment: Why do you think an 'anchor' is needed?

Comment: Is your question about past perfect, or the difference between "on getting" and "to"? I'm not sure why you've given two sentences.

Comment: I included both sentences in case one should sound wrong and distract attention from the real issue.

Answer (score 3):

The past perfect must be used relative to some simple past time. This is a rule about meaning (semantics), not sentence structure (syntax), so that simple past time doesn't need to be explicitly stated if it can be inferred from the context.

In this case, the same sentence with an explicit simple past might be:

> Thanks to the marketing tactics, unprepared shoppers usually buy products that they hadn’t intended to **when they entered the store**.

Since we can infer that shoppers entered the store, and had certain intentions when they did, this is a reasonable simple past time to infer.

That is just one interpretation. The simple past time might also be:

> ...**before they left home**
> or
> ...**when they decided to go shopping**

If it's important what the simple past time is, then the writer should state it. If it doesn't really matter, then it's common to leave it open to interpretation. In this case, it doesn't matter when the shopper formed their intent. It's only important that marketing influenced their shopping behaviour after.

Comment: Is your spelled-out version, with an explicit simple past anchor, really acceptable with the present-tense "buy" in the main clause in addition to past perfect and simple past?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, all my examples are natural.

Comment: What's the implied past-tense anchor in this definition of" "deep-six"?  "to decide not to do or use something that you had planned to do or use"

Comment: @Apollyon What do you think it is?